# I need to setup one instance of Laravel to run the another application using subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I don't like to modify the functioning of any of the code for example.com . After the setup
the objective is to use one instance of Laravel and have the domain/database structure of the image below and the following user interface pages.

```
info1.example.com

info2.example.com

info3.example.com
```

these all are run from example.com. Like example.com main domain run info1.example.com, and other's also run different address from example.com. how can i do that?

Comment: Hi, one application per sub-domain?

Comment: @hmrneves yes it is. there are six applications i have to enter a subdomain under one main domain.

Comment: You must create virtual subdomains that point to the folders of your projects or projects. search how to create subdomains for your server